# How to open new fxml view after click button - JavaFX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

Hi I have problem with open new window fxml view after click button. Main window display, in main view i have six buttons. I'd like to i click button opened new window. However while I click button, exception is displayed:
      java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

I try different solutions found in internet but display this exception. Mainly i try modify code in my switch function, responsible for display new view. I think that problem is here or code in main class.

```
Main class:
    public class Main extends Application {
         public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
           AnchorPane pane =   FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/mainView.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Init");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Stop");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
MainController.java
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private Button addChangeMainButton;

    @FXML
    private Button viewChangesButton;

    @FXML
    private Button addChangeBoughtButton;

    @FXML
    private Button viewContractsButton;

    @FXML
    private Button addContractButton;

    @FXML
    private Button viewStatisticsButton;




    @FXML
    void chooseViewAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Button button = (Button) event.getSource();
        String buttonId = button.getId();
        MainLogic mainl = new MainLogic();
        mainl.chooseView(buttonId);

    }

}
```

```
public class MainLogic {
   private String chooseView;



   public void chooseView(String chooseView) throws IOException {
       switch (chooseView) {
           case "addChangeMainButton":
               FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("addChangeVIEW.fxml"));
               Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load();
               Stage stage = new Stage();
               stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
               stage.show();

               break;

           case "viewChangesButton":
               System.out.println("viewChangesButton");

               break;

           case "addChangeBoughtButton":
               System.out.println("addChangeBoughtButton");

               break;
           case "viewContractsButton":
               System.out.println("viewContractsButton");

               break;

           case "addContractButton":
               System.out.println("addContractButton");
               break;

           case "viewStatisticsButton":
               System.out.println("viewStatisticsButton");
               break;

               default:
                   System.out.println("default");
                   break;

       }
   }


}
```

```
mainView.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.controller.MainController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="addChangeMainButton" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="45.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseViewAction" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Add Change" />
      <Button fx:id="viewChangesButton" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="283.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseViewAction" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="View Changes" />
      <Button fx:id="addChangeBoughtButton" layoutX="217.0" layoutY="45.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseViewAction" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Change Bought/Sold" />
      <Button fx:id="viewContractsButton" layoutX="225.0" layoutY="283.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseViewAction" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="View Contracts" />
      <Button fx:id="addContractButton" layoutX="403.0" layoutY="45.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseViewAction" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Add Contract" />
      <Button fx:id="viewStatisticsButton" layoutX="403.0" layoutY="283.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseViewAction" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="View Statistics" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

```
addChangeVIEW.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.controller.addChangeController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="263.0" layoutY="210.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

```
addChangeController.java
package com.controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class addChangeController {

    @FXML
    private Button button;

}
```

```
module-info.java

module ProjectCPApril {
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    exports com.controller to javafx.graphics;
    opens com.controller to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.logic to javafx.graphics;
    opens com.logic to javafx.fxml;

}
```

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at ProjectCPApril/com.logic.MainLogic.chooseView(MainLogic.java:27)
    at ProjectCPApril/com.controller.MainController.chooseViewAction(MainController.java:43)
    ... 58 more
Stop

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Can you provide the fxml files as well

Comment: I attached two files .fxml

Comment: I couldnt find any error with the demo, except that you have not provided fx:controller="com.controller.addChangeController" in addChangeVIEW.fxml. Can you provide the addChangeController.java

Comment: Ok, I added also module-info.java because i use sdk 11

Comment: Ok. I am checking with jdk8 and everything is workign well with what you have given. And sorry that I dont have a working environment for jdk 11.. may be some one will look into this. Good luck :)

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/RestaurantOrdersDuplicateFX

Comment: The exception is telling you the location is not set on the `FXMLLoader`. This means `getClass().getResource(...)` is return null and that means the resource could not be found at the specified location. Where is `addChangeVIEW.fxml` relative to the `MainLogic` class? Because if it's not in the same package the given path won't work.

Comment: `addChangeVIEW.fxml`  is in folder `resources`, `MainLogic.java` is in package 'com.logic'  and all files `*Controller.java are com.controller`

Comment: If `resources` is the root of the classpath, try using `"/addChangeVIEW.fxml"` (notice the `/`, that makes the path absolute). If `resources` is a package, then try `"/resources/addChangeView.fxml"`. For more information, see the [documentation of `Class#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)).

Comment: first path solved my problem :) Thank you very much :)

Comment: and your question Help me a lot, Thanks, Sometimes question helps people much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Copying information from comments into an answer*

The important part of the stack trace is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at ProjectCPApril/com.logic.MainLogic.chooseView(MainLogic.java:27)
    at ProjectCPApril/com.controller.MainController.chooseViewAction(MainController.java:43)
    ... 58 more
```

That tells you that the `FXMLLoader`'s location is `null` when you call `load`. As you're setting it via `Class.getResource` that means said method is returning `null`. When `getResource` returns `null` that means the resource could not be found with the given path.

You're currently using `"addChangeVIEW"` as the path, but you say:

> `addChangeVIEW.fxml` is in folder `resources`, `MainLogic.java` is in package `com.logic`

Since your path has no leading `/` it is relative to the `Class` you call `getResource` on. Since you use `MainLogic.class` the path gets resolved to `com/logic/addChangeVIEW.fxml`—that is not where you have the resource. You've put the resource at the root of the classpath, which can retrieved by using an *absolute* path: `"/addChangeVIEW.fxml"`.

See [`Class.getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) for more information.